# Tricky Macro in C

Tags: c, embedded, powerpc

I've got such a statement for a PowerPC and don't know how it works

```
#define XOR(A,D) (*(volatile unsigned int*)(volatile void*)((unsigned char*)0UL + (A)) ^= (D))
```

which is called(for example)

```
unsigned int a = 3;
unsigned int b = 50;
XOR((unsigned int)&a,b);
```

With a gcc for standard PC it does not compile, in my environment it did, so I ask myself: wtf...

Comment: Well first off, you have an extra `)` at the end of your `XOR` call...

Comment: What is a `volatile void`?

Comment: @harper: it's actually `volatile void *` and it's a pointer to a volatile memory location (e.g. a memory-mapped register) which can be cast to any type - it seems to be a redundant cast though (see answer below).

Comment: @PaulR How can be something volatile if it doesn't has a size? How can a `void` be changed so that the compiled code does not trust its value? Or did I missed something with `void`? -- Just curious.

Comment: @harper: think of `void *p` as a "pointer to anything" and `volatile void *p` as a "pointer to anything, where the 'anything' is to be treated as volatile". Compare/contrast with e.g. `const void *p`.

Comment: @PaulR What's the difference between volatile and non-volatile void* when all I can do with the pointer is casting to another pointer what requires a cast anyway?

Comment: @harper: well at the very least you should get a warning if you try to cast to a non-volatile pointer type, or pass such a volatile pointer to a function which takes a non-volatile pointer, just as when you try to cast away const-ness from a const pointer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63940/discussion-between-harper-and-paul-r).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an unnecessarily convoluted macro for toggling bits at hard-coded addresses. These addresses are probably memory-mapped register addresses. The `A` and `D` are clues here: `A` = address, `D`  = data. So typically if you have a register at address 0x100 and you want to toggle its least significant bit, you might write something like:

```
XOR(0x100, 0x01);
```

A much simpler version would just be:

```
#define XOR(A, D) ((*(volatile int *)(A)) ^= (D))
```

It's not clear why the original author used multiple casts and added the hard-coded address to a NULL pointer. At a guess, the former may be there to get rid of a compiler warning, the latter may have been to allow for a different register base address at some point.

Comment: As far as the convoluted cast series, it may help the compiler pick the right/best instruction encoding.

Comment: WOW... This answer fits exactly the use of the code in my environment, makes sense... I test the use without the XOR-Code and I don't get Data out of my Chip! So thanks a lot!!

Comment: Nevermind, whatever the case, I didn't see it, and I edited my comment

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: no problem - I was just a bit confused by your comments.

Comment: Always use uintx_t when doing bitwise operations. Don't use signed ints. In the case of a Power PC, you'd most likely want this to be uint32_t.

Comment: @Lundin: true - I was just sticking with the original coding style.

Comment: The `(volatile void*)` cast in the original seems superfluous, but the `(unsigned char*)` cast is probably there to avoid the compiler using alias rules to optimize things in unexpected ways (that introduce undefined behavior). To be honest, even though I suspect that's why the cast is there, I'm not sure that it's sufficient to portably avoid aliasing issues.

Answer (score 2):

It is an incredibly obfuscated way of writing

```
*(volatile uint32_t*)a ^= b;
```

(I picked uint32_t because it was stated that the CPU was a PowerPC)

Whenever you see people trying to re-invent the C language with their own obscure macro language, you can be certain that the program is of questionable quality. In this case, it is obvious that the programmer is very insecure about how C works and I'd regard the rest of their code with lots of scepticism.

Do not use function-like macros in this case.

Answer (score -2):

The additional conversion is to reduce MISRA checking warnings. [Here](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwj7kMTy1LTHAhWIJJQKHb-1AxE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcache.freescale.com%2Ffiles%2F32bit%2Fdoc%2Feng_bulletin%2FEB793.pdf&ei=kDXUVfuIEojJ0AS_646IAQ&usg=AFQjCNE9aOGW99HkO6saBYeFfoI6pz0OJA&bvm=bv.99804247,d.dGo) is the reference.